# How to merge data from various csv files to one csv file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 12 csv files containing salary data for each month. Naming convention is YYYYMMDD. For example, salary data for january is stored in a csv file named 20200131. I want to read all csv files and merge salary data for all employees in one single csv file. Header for each column should be Sal_Jan, Sal_Feb and so on while name of employee present in all csv files should be used only once.

January data stored in 20200131.csv as:

| Name | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20000 |
| B | 25000 |

February data stored in 20200229.csv as:

| Name | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| A | 21000 |
| B | 26000 |

Expected Output is:

| Name | Sal_Jan | Sal_Feb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20000 | 21000 |
| B | 25000 | 26000 |

I have used following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:/Users/Akshay/Documents/Question 2'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=1)
print(frame)
```

This code produces output where names are repeated for each month.
Also, how to change header for each month salary column automatically using file name.

Sample input files [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HQOitDGL4mxaqGgqp0afI1q6NzkLm0Vw?usp=sharing).

Comment: It would help if you provided a reproducible input.

Comment: There are many ways to do that, it depends on what the CSVs contains. 
Are the names for each month the same? Or is it dynamic?

Comment: I have added a link to sample input files.

Comment: Hello @AkshayPandey , that's good but not ideal. If you see my answer below, in future it would be slightly better if you provided a reproducible input in the format I have suggested in my answer with `df1 =...` and `df2 =...` . This is just to make it easier/more convenient for people trying to help, that's all. Does my solution below answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So try this. It worked for me. I created csv files with the file names as you specified, and the output is printed as I have shown it. This should be the complete solution with comments. If you have further questions, do ask.

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar as cl
import glob
    
path = r'C:/Users/Akshay/Documents/Question 2'

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

# Need to sort the files so that the columns are in order from Month 1 -> 12
all_files.sort()

# The following function converts the month number to "Sal_Jan",
# "Sal_Feb", etc. The index -8 to -6 is the position in the file
# name where the month number shows up.
# 


def f(fn): return str("Sal_" + cl.month_abbr[int(fn[-8:-6])])


li = []

# The first column in the data frame will be the "Name" column.
# The usecols method is saying to get the 0-th column
li.append(pd.read_csv(all_files[0], index_col=None, header=0, usecols=[0]))
for filename in all_files:
    # As each file is accessed, it is only appending the salary data
    # and is converting the month column name to the specified one
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=[1], header=0, names=[f(filename)])
    li.append(df)

# Specified the Name column as an index, so that the 0,1,2 index is removed.
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=1).set_index('Name')
print(frame)
```

So, after formatting the csv files as you have shown, and populating with some data, this is how the output appears:

```
      Sal_Jan  Sal_Feb  Sal_Mar  Sal_Apr  Sal_May  Sal_Jun
Name                                                      
A       20000    30000    30255    30510    30765    31020
B       21000    31000    31255    31510    31765    32020
C       22000    32000    32255    32510    32765    33020
D       24000    34000    34255    34510    34765    35020
E       28000    38000    38255    38510    38765    39020
F       10000    20000    20255    20510    20765    21020
G       11000    21000    21255    21510    21765    22020
H       14000    24000    24255    24510    24765    25020
I       13000    23000    23255    23510    23765    24020
J       22500    32500    32755    33010    33265    33520
K       23500    33500    33755    34010    34265    34520
```

Note that the extra line between the column heading and the data is NOT an extra row (ie not a NULL row). It is printed that way in the console to show that "Name" column is an index.

EDIT: So I just noticed that you provided sample files, so I re-ran my code with your sample files, and this was the output:

```
      Sal_Jan  Sal_Feb  Sal_Mar  Sal_Apr  Sal_May  Sal_Jun  Sal_Jul  Sal_Aug  Sal_Sep  Sal_Oct
Name                                                                                          
A       10000    15000    20000    25000    30000    35000    40000    45000    50000    55000
B       10000    15000    20000    25000    30000    35000    40000    45000    50000    55000
C       10000    15000    20000    25000    30000    35000    40000    45000    50000    55000
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried something similar but your code is quite comprehensive and easy to understand. Worked for me.

Comment: You know what's weird, the way how you originally did it was supposed to work according to the docs. But you're right, it reprints the name column each time. According to the docs, concat is supposed to print it out only the first time. Very strange. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `reduce` from `functools` to merge the dataframes.

```
#import package
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

#reproducing your dataframe images...
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name" : ["A","B"], 
                     "Salary" : [20000,25000]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Name" : ["A","B"], 
                     "Salary" : [21000,26000]})

#Create a list of all dfs
dfs = [df1, df2,]

#merge on name
df3 = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Name'), dfs)

#rename the columns
df3.columns = ['Name', 'Sal_Jan', 'Sal_Feb']
```

Alternative way to rename specific columns only:

```
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need to concat, but to merge dataframes. If you think then to have different employees in each month, the best choice is a *full outer join* the dataframes.

The command is this:

```
pd.merge(first_pd,second_pd,on='Name',how='outer')
```

that works if your dataframes always have the column referring to the name of the employee named "Name". *outer* means that if an employee name does not match for any dataframe, its place will be replaced there with a **NaN**

You can browse the whole solution in this gist: https://gist.github.com/irongraft/c12895419fa241adc03ec0635e45aebe

ciao

Answer (score 0):

Try this easy solution:

```
import os 
import panda as pd

directory = r'SalaryFilesDirectoryPath'
dfresult=pd.DataFrame({})

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    df=pd.read_csv(filename)
    dfresult['Name']=df['Name']
    dfresult[filename[8:-4]]=df['Salary']
    
dfresult.to_csv('outputname.csv')
```

PS: this will work only if you name each csv in an alphabetical order otherwise, you would have unsorted months + folder must contain only CSV salary files + you would need to upgrade it if you have different names in each csv.